# Minimum number of observations in order to trust a difference?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean

I'm doing an experiment to measure a very small number. For example, first I expect a measurement to be 10.0005 and then after introducing a variable, I expect the next measurement to be 10.0007

The problem is, each time I take the first measurement, the result could be anywhere from 8.0 to 12.0 - I believe if I take the measurement many times, the average will come out to my expected value. And the same for the second measurement, after introducing the variable, each individual measurement varies, but it should eventually average out to my expected value.

Now, if I just compare a single first measurement (without variable) to a single final measurement (with variable) even if the observed difference matches my expected difference, it could be a coincidence, considering how much each individual measurement can vary.

My question is:

- Is there a minimum number of times I should take measurements before & after introducing the variable, so that when I compare the averages, I can trust the observed difference is not a coincidence?

If so, how can I calculate that minimum number so I know how many times to take measurements?

Comment: Hi Dingredient, I think it would be beneficial to those answering if you clarified what the variable you are introducing is and what you are measuring?

Comment: Welcome to CV! I edited the title of your question to (hopefully) better reflect your question. What you are asking for is the essence of hypothesis testing and sample size estimation. I think the answer of @BruceET is a good start. You may also want to read up on these two subjects a bit. **As to the close votes**: This question may be very basic, but the purpose is clearly explained in the question. If someone has never been introduced to hypothesis testing, this is a very reasonable question.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should consider a paired experiment to
study differences such as the difference between 10.0005 and 10.0007 you mentioned, in order to look just at
the effect of 'introducing the variable' of interest.
You should obtain several such differences (such as $D_i = 0.0002.$

After you have done this several times $i = 1, 2, \dots, n,$ you can find the average difference $\bar D$ and the standard deviation of the differences $S_D.$ Then you can make a 'confidence interval' to give you an idea how big
an effect the 'variable' has.

Key formulas are $$\bar D = \frac 1n \sum_{i-1}^n D_i = (D_1 + D_2 + \cdots + D_n)/n$$ and
$$S_D = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (D_i - \bar D)^2}.$$

If you have at least
 $n = 30$ differences, a 95% confidence interval would be approximately $$\bar D \pm 2.0 \frac{S_D}{\sqrt{n}}.$$
If it not feasible to get as many as 30 differences,
you might still be able to make a confidence interval, but the factor $2.0$ would be larger.  [You can google
't confidence interval', if you don't already know about this.]

If your confidence interval doesn't include $0,$ then you can be reasonably sure you have a consistent effect
due to your 'variable'. Also, you will have a rough idea how variable the effect is.

It wouldn't work nearly as well to collect $n_b$ values before
introducing the 'variable' and another $n_a$ values after.  You could look at the mean before and the mean after, but you say those measurements are subject to huge variability (between 8 and 12). It crucial to keep track of individual before-after *pairs* of measurements.  This is the difference between 'paired' data and 'two-sample' data. From what you say, I
think you need paired data.

From your question, it is difficult to know how much you know about statistics. If you have follow-up questions after reading this and can't answer them by googling various phrases, please leave a comment and maybe one of us can help.

---

Example using R statistical software. Thirty differences:

```
 d
 [1] 0.00021 0.00022 0.00026 0.00024 0.00018
 [6] 0.00019 0.00020 0.00025 0.00022 0.00020
[11] 0.00017 0.00019 0.00021 0.00019 0.00016
[16] 0.00020 0.00024 0.00021 0.00025 0.00016
[21] 0.00020 0.00018 0.00018 0.00022 0.00015
[26] 0.00019 0.00024 0.00023 0.00020 0.00022
```

Sample mean $\bar D$ and sample standard deviation $S_D:$

```
mean(d);  sd(d)
[1] 0.0002053333
[1] 2.849481e-05
```

95% confidence interval $(0.000195, 0.000216).$

```
t.test(d)$conf.int
[1] 0.0001946932 0.0002159735
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95

pm=c(-1,1)
mean(d) + pm*2*sd(d)/sqrt(30)
[1] 0.0001949285 0.0002157382 # approximation
```